# Labeling points on the x axis in matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, datatables

I have a table, named "Log_mean" a quick example of this:

| numberID | Score | Model |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.3 | a |
| 2 | 0.2 | b |

I have Plotted the ID against score using the following code:

```
plot(Log_mean.numberID, Log_mean.Score, '--o');
title('Mean of Log scores.')
ylabel('Score')
xlabel('Models')
```

Which produces the following graph:
[image: Log mean graph]

My question is, as each circle represents the score for a particular model, is it possible for me to name each of those points on the x-axis using the column model in my table?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you just need a categorical axis

```
xlabs = categorical( Log_mean.Model, Log_mean.Model ); % using the 2nd input preserves ordering
```

Then you can plot it

```
plot( xlabs, Log_mean.Score, '--o' );
```

If you want to combine the model and the ID, you can do that a number of ways. Something like this would work:

```
xlabs = arrayfun( @(x) sprintf('%d - %s', Log_mean.numberID(x), Log_mean.Model{x}), 1:height(Log_mean), 'uni', 0 );
xlabs = categorical( xlabs, xlabs );

plot( xlabs, Log_mean.Score, '--o' );
```